# Как сохранить и загрузить все title и description заданый yoast seo?

Tags: wordpress, yoast

На сайте установлен Yoast Seo, в настройках есть возможность сделать экспорт и импорт настроек самого плагина. Там я нашел вкладку "Экспорт ключевых фраз" который генерирует в csv url, title,discription. Но нет функции импорта этих данных.

Возможно есть возможность массово загрузить тайтл и дескрипшн на сайт?

Comment: Покажите где найти эту вкладку, не смог найти ее. Но в целом вам могу помочь шаблоны для типов постов и терминов. Или же можете напрямую писать мету. Объясните задачу детальнее

Comment: http://joxi.ru/ZrJ98VqCMVEEjA.  вы не смогли найти потому что это в PRO версии, в обычной вроде такого функционала нет

Comment: А станддартный импорт - не, разве?

Comment: Короче данные для постов храняться в мете, данные для терминов в опциях. Написать свой скрипт пол часа работы)